# Where are my downloads from download manager going?

Tags: android, audio, android-download-manager

I am downloading audio files from a parse server. The results after running the code below is that when the client clicks the notification, it plays. However, when the client closes the music player, and opens it back up, it is no longer listed. My question is, where is this file located? I have seen methods for setting the external storage location, but I would like for it to download to the internal storage with the other downloads. How can I accomplish this?

```
    private class DownloadFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.downloading), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String currentSong = urls[0];
        try {
            downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(currentSong);

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return currentSong;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.download_complete), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
```

Comment: I expected it to download to `downloads` directory by default, but if it does not - why can;t you sat the output directory to downloads derectory manually?

Comment: I seen a method to set the directory for external storage but did not see one for internal storage. Do you know how to?

Comment: what do you mean by *eternal storage*